# How do I draw 3-D axes in TIKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, physics

Can someone help me draw this? I need it to show the effect of a rotated polarizing component, and things always looks better in tikz, my my skills are sub-standard.

[image]

Comment: With tikz-3dplot this is really straightforward. Are you aware of this package?

Comment: no how does it work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. On this site there is an expectation that posters will make an attempt at the solution (even if it's just a start), rather than just asking for someone to do it for them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather basic task for the `tikz-3dplot` package and the `3d` library. The package allows you to obtain orthographic projections for any view angles. The `3d` library allows you to switch to a plane and project things therein.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-30}{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_rotated_coords,thick,>={Latex[length=5pt]},
font=\sffamily,pics/.cd,
3d xy axes/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{code={
 \draw[->] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[pos=1.05] {$#1$};
 \draw[->] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1.05] {$#2$};
 \node at (-1.5,-1.5,0) {$#3$};
}}]
 \foreach \X/\Y/\S [count=\Z] in {x/y/S,x/y/S',x'''/y'''/S'''} 
 {\path (0,0,6*\Z) pic {3d xy axes={\X/\Y/\S}};
 \draw[red,->] (0,0,-3+6*\Z) -- (0,0,3+6*\Z);}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=12,rotate=30]
  \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[pos=1.05] {$x'$};
  \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[pos=1.05] {$y'$};
  \draw (1,0) arc(0:-30:1) node[pos=0.5,right,transform shape]{$\theta$};
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (0,-3.2,6) {Incident beam};
 \node[anchor=north,align=left] at (0,-3.2,12) {Rotated polarizing\\ element};
 \node[anchor=north] at (0,-3.2,18) {Emerging beam};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]